# JavaFX Label that dynamically displays a value calculated using some controllers

Tags: java, javafx

I have some JavaFX controllers implemented with listeners (eg. a `Slider`, some `RadioButton`s in a `ToggleGroup`). I would like to have a `Label` or a `TextField` (I think the former suits better from my request) that displays a number resulting from an operation made with the numbers selected through my controllers. The `Label` should update the displayed value automatically everytime the controllers are used by the user. How can I achieve this?

**A Basic Example**

```
private Slider firstSlider = new Slider(0, 255, 0);
private Slider secondSlider = new Slider (0, 15, 0);
private Label firstSliderValue = new Label("256 bytes (64 words)");
private Label secondSliderValue = new Label("0.413818359375 KHz");

// I would like this Label to display for example 
// double math = secondSlider.getValue() * firstSlider.getValue();
private Label finalValueLabel; 

firstSlider.valueProperty().addListener((ov, old_val, new_val) -> {
    int value = (int) Math.round(new_val.doubleValue());
    firstSlider.setValue(value);
    System.out.println(value);
    firstSliderValue.setText(getDisplayMemory(value));
});

    secondSlider.valueProperty().addListener((ov, old_val, new_val) -> {
    int value = (int) Math.round(new_val.doubleValue());
    secondSlider.setValue(value);
    System.out.println(value);
    secondSliderValue.setText(getDisplayFrequency(value));
});
```

`getDisplayFrequency` and `getDisplayMemory` are just some methods for displaying a certain text on the `firstSliderValue` and on the `secondSliderValue` depending on the values selected via the `Sliders`, but they are not necessary for my question.

*EDIT:*
Added a basic and simple example.

Comment: Use a `Binding`... You can bind the `textProperty` of the `Label` to another object's property and show it.

Comment: Ok, i was thinking about that too. But how can I update my value (that I want to display) dynamically using the values from more than one controller?

Comment: Please provide some very basic code (just some controller examples and the `Label`), otherwise this will extend to `n` comments containing sub-questions and answers... With the example code, readers (like me) will get a better idea of how to solve your special problem.

Comment: Creating a binding that depends on multiple properties is possible, but it would be much easier to answer if you could describe the desired output based on the state of those objects.

Comment: I have put some code in the edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Bindings.createStringBinding`

e.g.

```
label.textProperty().bind(
    Bindings.createStringBinding(
        () -> String.format("%.2f", firstSlider.getValue()*secondSlider.getValue()), 
        firstSlider.valueProperty(), secondSlider.valueProperty()
    )
);
```

And you can improve your other code too if you want.

e.g.

```
firstSliderValue.textProperty().bind(
    Bindings.createStringBinding(
        () -> getDisplayMemory((int) Math.round(firstSlider.getValue())),
        firstSlider.valueProperty()
    )
);
secondSliderValue.textProperty().bind(
    Bindings.createStringBinding(
        () -> getDisplayFrequency((int) Math.round(secondSlider.getValue())),
        secondSlider.valueProperty()
    )
);
```

Comment: Thank you. What if I need to perform my calculation also with some values coming from `RadioButton`s in a `ToggleGroup`. I have also a listener for that. What should I include in the `.createStringBinding`?

Comment: can you post it too?

Comment: I have solved it, I tried in the same way using `.selectedToggleProperty()`. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Can you explain what is exactly the improvement you suggest and how would it affect my code? thank you

Comment: you should be binding the sliderValues too - without using `addListener` as you can see in the second part of my answer